# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Java3D

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, java-3d

I'm trying to develop a java3d application, i try everything, i just download the jogamp-platform because how i could read in many websites the java3d is obsolete and for mac os x you need this, i put them all in /System/Frameworks/Java/Extensions where are my .jar files in order to not add to the classpath in Eclipse but it still getting the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/AbstractGraphicsDevice
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$1.run(Pipeline.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline.createPipeline(Pipeline.java:138)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:926)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:280)
    at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.<clinit>(Canvas3D.java:3862)
    at Apartado_a.<init>(Apartado_a.java:17)
    at Apartado_a.main(Apartado_a.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.AbstractGraphicsDevice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 10 more
```

These are the files inside extensions folder:

```
 j3daudio.jar
 j3dcore.jar
 j3dutils.jar
 joal-natives-macosx-universal.jar
 jogl-all.jar
 gluegen-rt.jar
 gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar
```

Regards!

Comment: Why don't you want to add them to the classpath?

Comment: Well, when i add the JRE in Build Path all the jar files include in my project so there's no point to adding again to the classpath

Comment: Well, finally I fixed it, just a problem with new JDK version, 1.7 not works with Java3D, at least in Mountain Lion, just set up to 1.6 or minor version works fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X comes pre-installed with Java 3D version 1.3.  You can find these files in /System/Library/Java/Extensions.  If you need to install Java 3D version 1.5 (and it sounds like you do), then you can use this installer: http://create.ife.no/vr/tools/j3d/java3d_1_5_2-macosx.pkg.zip

Comment: Well, nothing changes, now it's getting another noclassdeffounderror... this is driving my nuts! 

...  

Exception in thread "J3D-Renderer-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apple/awt/ComponentModel
 at com.sun.opengl.impl.JAWT_DrawingSurface.GetDrawingSurfaceInfo0(Native Method)...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the /System/Frameworks/Java/Extensions folder for this.

Instead, include the relevant libraries in the lib/ folder of your application.  Also, check which version of the JDK you are using.  I believe there are some issues with Java3D running on the newer Apple-provided JVMs versus the older Oracle/Sun provided ones.

Comment: There's no lib folder inside my project, you mean Eclipse folder?

Comment: Whatever you are using as a local classpath, make sure the libraries are there.  That is usually just a lib/ folder, but it could be anything.

Comment: I'm using the JRE System Library as a classpath where the librarys are there and always gets the same error even adding another folder with the same jar files gets the same error, i believe i'm missing some library but i don't know which one.